# Linking my CSS file to my Django Project

Tags: css, django

I am trying to link my css files to my Django Project. Not sure where the error is.

This is how my settings file look like:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    '/Users/IMAC/work3/Blog/Blog/polls/static',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/Users/IMAC/work3/Blog/Blog/polls/static'
```

This is how my html file looks like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}gameserver.css">
```

This is how my css file looks like:

```
#tuna{color:red;} 
body {background-color:blue;}
```

Must i change anything else? Why might be my error? Not sure where I am making my mistake...

Where should my static folder be? inside the app or inside the same folder as the app?

Comment: at what location gameserver.css is searching currently

Comment: in my static folder which is in my app polls...

Comment: Post here `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` from your settings.py file

Comment: Never hardcode an absolute path !!!!

Comment: @jpic agree with you....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake is i forgot context_instance=RequestContext(request).

`If {{ STATIC_URL }} isn't working in your template, you're probably not using RequestContext when rendering the template`

Answer (score 1):

Remove `'/Users/IMAC/work3/Blog/Blog/polls/static'` from `STATICFILES_FINDERS = (`

And your STATIC_ROOT  should be

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/Users/IMAC/work3/Blog/Blog/polls/static/'
```

and

```
STATIC_URL  = '/static/'
```

Comment: gameserver.css   will be in your `STATIC_ROOT`

Comment: what about STATICFILES_DIRS? do i need to change it as well?

Comment: put `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` above `STATICFILES_FINDERS`

Comment: `STATICFILES_DIRS `is Additional locations of static files . so if you have other locations too then keep it

Comment: should it the static folder be outside or inside the app?

Comment: For example if you have app called 'userprofile' and you want to put userprofile related css in that folder then you can add in `STATICFILES_DIRS` like `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + '/userprofile/static/'`

Comment: i prefer app related css/js in that app .

Comment: i keep getting this error when i run server: [06/Jun/2012 04:33:23] "GET /js/libs/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2141 does it matter affect the css?

Comment: to see whether css is loading or not , use firebug 's Net tab.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12189/discussion-between-lakesh-and-priyank-patel)

Answer (score 0):

You've misunderstood what the various settings do:

- [`STATIC_FILES_FINDERS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-finders) is a list of Python classes which Django uses to search for static files, it is not a list of places where static files are stored.
- [`STATIC_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-STATIC_ROOT) is the directory where the static files are stored.
- [`STATIC_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-STATIC_URL) is the URL that should point to the static files.

In your case you want something like this:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
STATIC_ROOT = '/Users/IMAC/work3/Blog/Blog/polls/static' 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```